# java JSON and string in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I am querying a database through php in android.  Here is my relevant code

```
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuilder sb = null;

is = entity.getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
   sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
result = sb.toString();    
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
```

Here is the link and returned data I am trying to parse.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522%2C151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCX8PnG_dSJvCMmQPN1Zjbpi_RcokyiOss

Everything went fine till the last statement.  When I try to print out the length of result, it's of correct length.  However, if I try to print out result using

```
Log.e ("ERROR", result);
```

and adb logcat to look at the output,it's truncated.  So if the truncated string result was passed into JSONArray, it'll definitely crash.  It was always truncated after "Pyrmont Bay Wh", which is about 4048 characters down the returned value. So guess my question is why the variable "result" was truncated.  thanks

Comment: I think it is more of editor issue than truncate. Have you tried to parse it? If so, are you getting any error?

Comment: Print out the values of result (before you parse) and put them here.  Otherwise there is no way to know.  Also, is it possible this is a json object?

Answer (score 0):

Logcat truncates long strings.

```
$ adb logcat -g
/dev/log/main: ring buffer is 64Kb (63Kb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4076b
```

One thing you can do is split the string into printable chunks as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7606118/1309304):

```
    int maxLogSize = 1000;
    for(int i = 0; i <= veryLongString.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
        int start = i * maxLogSize;
        int end = (i+1) * maxLogSize;
        end = end > veryLongString.length() ? veryLongString.length() : end;
        Log.v(TAG, veryLongString.substring(start, end));
    }
```