# Buffer.prototype.toString doesn't print more than 500 characters

Tags: node.js, buffer

A http request is returning me a incomplete string.

```
https.get(url, function(res) {
 res.on('data', function(data) {
   translationData = data.toString();
    resolve(translationData);
    })
  });
```

I can't get more than 500 characters.

I suppose my code is vague, but what could cause this problem?

I've tried a lot of approaches but all of them failed.

I've something similar in [How to display long messages in logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606077/how-to-display-long-messages-in-logcat/7606118#7606118), but nothing compared in nodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response object you get from http.get is a *Stream*.
The 'data' event handler is called whenever a *chunk* of data is received. You need to handle all of the 'data' events and collect their payload until you get an 'end' event in order to get the entire response.

A simple way of doing this is using the [`concat-stream` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-stream).

```
var concat = require('concat-stream');
https.get(url, function(res) {
    res.pipe(concat(function(data) {
       // data is the entire response
    }));
}
```

To learn more about streams, read substack's [stream handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook)

Comment: It works. When I was learning node I didn't pay attention to the this theme.

I will read the book.  

Thank you for the kindness.