# How to copy texts of values inside variable when debugging, android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm debugging in **Android Studio** and
I'm trying to select xml value of a variable to check it's structure.
But i can't select the value. Neither **cmd+c** nor **cmd+v** works and right click is unavailable too.

[image]

Comment: Print it to the logcat instead?

Comment: first Right click on Writer then choose copy value and paste whenever you want

Comment: try this way to print  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606077/how-to-display-long-messages-in-logcat

Comment: @cricket_007, may be, I should do so.

Comment: @NiteshPareek, it doesn't work. I only get redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient#writer

Comment: @NiteshPareek, it works, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can right click on your variable "writer". Then there is option "Copy Value" and simply use that.

other way: when app in debug mode, right click on variable and select "Evaluate Expression" and then copy value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac, firstly check which keymap is set on your AndroidStudio.
- At Top Left AndroidStudio-> Preferences -> Keymap --> then from dropdown of keymaps select Eclipse for keymaps apply and ok.
Then you can use control+c for copy and control+v for paste while debugging.

- If you set keymaps Eclipse(Mac) then for copy use command+c and paste use command+v