# Is there any limit in Volley library to get number of data on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Is there any limit that Volley supports to JSON files?
I have more than 700 lines of data in JSON.
but I'm getting not the whole list of data.
Please tell me how can I get all data in response.

Comment: Are you displaying in logcat?

Comment: yes  but it showing few data not more than 50 data

Comment: It's not the problem with Volley!, it's the problem(limitation) of logcat for displaying limited size of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with Volley. It's a limitation of Logcat.

I hope [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606077/how-to-display-long-messages-in-logcat) will help you to display the whole response data in Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

No limits of response in volley library
but if you are using log-cat then it will show a limited data 
log-cat show only limited data only