# InputStreamReader returns only half of the html Document

Tags: java, android, logcat

I am building an app that fetches images from websites.
When i fetch html of the webpage , only half of the webpage is fetched by InputStreamReader.
Spent too much time searching for solution but none suggest how to fix the problem.
any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Here's the MainActivity.java
https://gist.github.com/sujayss81/e4237916c605be223c673af7cf8f40d4

Here are the logs

https://gist.github.com/sujayss81/774472fe274e7cf9ebfdd0388c3e3ab5

Comment: I think that your variable `result` is correctly populated, with the entire web page. But the output of `Log.i("Result",result);` is truncated, making you believe that the code is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code correctly fetches the entire web page. But the output of `Log.i("Result",result);` is truncated.

So if you want to increase this limit, consult these question:

- [Android - Set max length of logcat messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888654/android-set-max-length-of-logcat-messages)
- [How to display long messages in logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606077/how-to-display-long-messages-in-logcat)
- [What is the size limit for Logcat and how to change its capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321555/what-is-the-size-limit-for-logcat-and-how-to-change-its-capacity)